# Regex .htaccess rewrite url problem with dot/period

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I intend to redirect this url:

> `http://localhost/iiif/http/image-service/papyrus,1/full/400,300/0/default.jpg`

to

> `http://localhost/iiif/http/image.php?req=763648&id=papyrus,1&region=full&size=400,300&rotation=0&quality=default&format=jpg`

I have written the rewrite rule as:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /iiif/http/    
RewriteRule image-service/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*).(.*)$ image.php?req=763648&id=$1&region=$2&size=$3&rotation=$4&quality=$5&format=$6 [R=301,NC,L,P]
</IfModule>
```

The result is:

```
Array
(
    [req] => 763648
    [id] => papyrus,1
    [region] => full
    [size] => 400,300
    [rotation] => 0
    [quality] => default.jp.
)
```

instead of:

```
Array
(
    [req] => 763648
    [id] => papyrus,1
    [region] => full
    [size] => 400,300
    [rotation] => 0
    [quality] => default
    [format] => jpg
)
```

I suspect that this is due to the presence of a period/dot(.) in the url. How can I correct it?

Comment: Why are you using `R=301` and `P` flags together? Do you want to proxy or redirect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape the period before the file extension

```
/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)\.(.*)
```

Note the added backslash `\` between the last two `(.*)` capture groups

Comment: Same result as before

Comment: regex101 throws an error with this pattern using unescaped backslashes, but this pattern works as expected and may be worth a try: `\/(.*)\/(.*)\/(.*)\/(.*)\/(.*)\.(.*)` [see here](https://regex101.com/r/liFcRV/1)

Comment: No luck. Seem to be something .htaccess specific.

Comment: Yes. you were correct. It was due to browser cache problem.

Comment: @JRiggles regex101 is only throwing an error for unescaped (forward) slashes because you are using _slashes_ as the regex delimiter (you can change it). Apache/mod_rewrite uses _spaces_ (or double quotes) as the regex/argument delimiters.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you use this rewrite rule like this:

```bash
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /iiif/http/    
RewriteRule image-service/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/.]+)\.(.*)$ image.php?req=763648&id=$1&region=$2&size=$3&rotation=$4&quality=$5&format=$6 [NC,L,QSA]
```

**Breakdown:**

- Negated character class `[^/]+` instead of greedy `.*` that may match anything
- Removal of `R=301` and `P` flags from rewrite since all you want is an internal rewrite
- Escaping last dot to match extension

Comment: Same result. Nothing changes.

Comment: That means it is old browser cache since I have removed `R=301` so URL must not change in browser. Test it from a new browser or better to test in command line curl.

Comment: The previous answer also worked. Sorry I had to accept the answer as it was posted before. So many thanke for pointing out the cache problem.

Comment: It is totally fine but do change your flags to `[NC,L,QSA]`